# iOS - Folder animation in application

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, cocoa, animation, directory

How do I create a folder-like animation in my app? I want to do something like the any.do list in terms of animation. I tap on a title, and all the info below scrolls down, and a new info appears (like folders or accordion).

What is the best way to do this?

Example:

```
Title
text 1
text 2
text 3

tap on title ->

Title
new text below title
text 1
text 2
text 3
```

Answer (score 8):

There's a great library called [JWFolder on Github](https://github.com/jwilling/JWFolders) that perfectly imitates the folder animation.

Here's what it does:

[image]

Hope this helps!

Comment: Awesome! It will surely help me a lot!